# understanding trans_new on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rescale

Coming from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248937/in-rs-scales-package-why-does-trans-new-use-the-inverse-argument) (pasted here)

```
trans_cube <- trans_new(name = "cube root",
                        transform = cube_root,
                        inverse = cube)

# dummy data
plot_data <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                        y = cube(1:10))

# without applying a transform
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
# applying a transform
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_trans(y = trans_cube)
```

Why the simple transformation of just adding a constant (`using scales::trans_new`) won't work?

```
trans_add <- trans_new(name = "add",
                         transform = function(x) x + 200,
                         inverse = function(x) x -200)
 
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +   geom_point() +  
coord_trans(y = trans_add )
```

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to back transform my y-axis and I need to do it using `coord_trans` or `scale_y_continuous` or similar.

**UPDATE**

I managed to show the back transformation with custom breaks by using the following, however I would like to know why the `trans_new` doesn't work.

```
fun_sc_back <- function(x){x*187+266} # transform 
fun_sc <- function(x){(x-266)/187}    # inverse 

p_tr + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks =fun_sc(c(250, 500, 750)), labels=fun_sc_back)
```